# ul element jumps out of div when inserting

Tags: html, ckeditor

I have following problem with the latest version of CKEDITOR.

**Reproduction steps**

1. Open the following link
   http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/fullpreset.html
2. Switch to sourcecode mode in the CKEditor
3. Insert the following code

```html
<h3 class="foo title">title</h3>
<div class="foo content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur ...</div>
```

4. Switch back to WYSIWIG mode
5. Place the mousecursor behind the lorem ipsum... text
6. Add a line-break with the "enter" key
7. Press the "ul" icon in the editor to generate an ul list and add some content to the first list item.
8. Switch back to sourcecode mode
9. Now you see the UL-list "jumped" out the div-element

```html
<h3>title</h3>
<div class="foo content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur ...</div>
<ul>
<li>asdfsadf</li>
</ul>
```

**Expected result**

The ul list should by stay inside the div and don't jump out of it.

**Actual result**

The inserted ul list jump out of div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the solution for this problem from the CKEDITOR lead developer ([Piotrek Koszuliński](https://github.com/Reinmar)).

**[Here his answer on GitHub](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/621#issuecomment-314455697):**

...

I'm afraid this can't work as you'd expect. At least, not by default. You're expecting a very special and specific behaviour from the editor which is close to "web page building", while CKEditor is focused on content creation.

So, what's the rule which the editor follows? The content is made out of blocks. Paragraph is a block, list is a block, heading is a block. You can't nest blocks within each other. You can't have heading inside a paragraph or list inside a heading. CKEditor 4 breaks this rule in some cases (you may create headings inside list items) but this is a cause of huge headaches that we have.

In your case, both of the divs are understood as blocks. Why? Because they contain text. Divs are tricky. Some people expect them to behave like paragraphs (hence the div enter mode) and some as containers for block content.

CKEditor 4 tries to implement both so it needs to differentiate between those two cases using a heuristic which I mentioned.

So, if you want your  to behave like a container, not a block, put paragraph inside it. E.g:

```html
<div class="foo content"><p>foo</p></div>
```

Now, if you click the list button the list will be created inside the div, not outside.

However, I really recommend you to split all this into two separate editors. Have the heading separately and the content separately. The way you want to use CKEditor is not recommended because it leads to a lot of problems. Use it well and you'll have much better control and results.